# Elastic Search: Query Filter not working with Scripts?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, opensearch

Basically i'm trying to get the `record_created_at` dates where day is Monday

I've wrote below `script` in `query`

**Query:**

```json
{
    "_source": "false",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "doc['record_created_at'].value.getDayOfWeek() == 1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "record_created_at_agg": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "record_created_at",
                "calendar_interval": "day",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "record_created_at"
    ],
    "size": 10000
}
```

But i'm getting the response without applying the filter in `query` like below:

**Response**:

```json
...
"aggregations": {
    "record_created_at_agg": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2023-05-08",
          "key": 1683504000000,
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2023-05-09",
          "key": 1683590400000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2023-05-10",
          "key": 1683676800000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
...
```

and i also tried another filter in `query` with `match`

```json
{
    "_source": "false",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "record_created_at": "2023-05-08T16:14:58.000Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "filtered_dates": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "record_created_at",
                "calendar_interval": "day",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "record_created_at"
    ],
    "size": 10000
}
```

Getting the response as expected, as below

**Response 2**

```json
  "aggregations": {
    "record_created_at_agg": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2023-05-08",
          "key": 1683504000000,
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first response is technically correct because you get 0 documents for May 9th (Tuesday) and 10th (Wednesday).

What you can do is to add `min_doc_count` to your `date_histogram` aggregation so as to only get Monday buckets

```
{
    "_source": "false",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "doc['record_created_at'].value.getDayOfWeek() == 1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "record_created_at_agg": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "record_created_at",
                "calendar_interval": "day",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "min_doc_count": 1               <------ add this
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "record_created_at"
    ],
    "size": 10000
}
```